# Best/Proper way to run an insert stored procedure in a loop c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, foreach

I'm stuck on the means to properly and best run a stored procedure to insert records through a foreach loop.

Here is what I have so far.

```
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CurrencyDb"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr)) {
    con.Open();
        foreach (ListItem i in DependenciesListBox.Items) {
            if (i.Selected) {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertDependency", con)) {
                    try {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrencyId", scopeidentity);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DependencyId", i.Value);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (SqlException sqlex) {
                        throw new Exception("SQL Exception on insert. " + sqlex.Message);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {
                        throw new Exception("Error adding dependencies. " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (ListItem i in AffectedListBox.Items) {
            if (i.Selected) {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertAffected", con)) {
                    try {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DependencyId", scopeidentity);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrencyId", i.Value);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (SqlException sqlex) {
                        throw new Exception("SQL Exception on insert. " + sqlex.Message);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {
                        throw new Exception("Error adding affected apps. " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Loops through Platform list box and for each item that's selected, add a record into the platform table in the database.
        foreach (ListItem i in PlatformListBox.Items) {
            if (i.Selected) {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertPlatform", con)) {
                    try {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrencyId", scopeidentity);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlatformId", i.Value);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (SqlException sqlex) {
                        throw new Exception("SQL Exception on insert. " + sqlex.Message);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {
                        throw new Exception("Error adding platforms. " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Doing it this way, I get the following error (Updated)

```
Uncaught Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Error adding dependencies. The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.
    at Function.Error.create (MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81:1)
    at Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._createPageRequestManagerServerError (MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81:1)
    at Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._parseDelta (MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81:1)
    at Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._onFormSubmitCompleted (MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81:1)
    at Array.<anonymous> (MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81:1)
    at MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81:1
    at Sys.Net.WebRequest.completed (MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onReadyStateChange (MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81:1)
```

Would anyone be able to let me know what the best practice is for doing this kind of thing?  Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Please add your error message as text, not an image. It makes it easier to read, and search for.

Comment: You're right, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `con.Open();` multiple times. Move it to

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr)) {
  con.Open();
  ...
```

See the first row in the **Exceptions** table:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I knew it was going to be something silly.  Let me try this out, thank you.

Comment: @David - because you have `con.Open();` in three different loops - remove all of them and leave only one as shown

Comment: Yes I removed all three and left one right after using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr)) {

I'll update my code.

Comment: Ok, I'll do so via text this time.

Comment: @David - you are running old code, make sure the binaries are rebuilt

Comment: I had sworn that I had cleaned and rebuilt.  That was it.  Thank you so much for your patience throughout all of that.

Comment: @David you bet, neighbour